# Add data-icon input to Wordpress custom menu links

Tags: menus, navigation, screen-options

I need to add a `data-icon=""` input to my Wordpress Custom Menu input box thing. This is so I can use an icon font and type the code in for a specific icon and in the CSS use pseudo elements to match it up and display the icon.

I've found loads of tutorials which show how to extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class so I can add an attribute, but none of them extend this into adding a new input box on the Wordpress Custom Menu screen (http://cl.ly/Sn0C) and then having the value of this displayed in the HTML.

I've used [this code](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/3802459) to add a data-icon input box on the Custom Menu admin screen (http://cl.ly/SmqM) but I'm not good enough at PHP to link it up to the `Walker_Nav_Menu` extension class to show the data-icon value in the HTML. Can anyone help me out? Thanks :)

I would prefer if this could be done in functions.php and/or without the use of a plugin. Thanks!

Btw, here is my `Walker_Nav_Menu` extension class code:

```
class data_type_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
           global $wp_query;
           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'     . esc_attr( $item->attr_title       ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="'    . esc_attr( $item->target           ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'       . esc_attr( $item->xfn              ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'      . esc_attr( $item->url              ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->data_icon )  ? ' data-icon="' . esc_attr( $item->data_icon        ) .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '';
           $append = '';

           if($depth != 0) {
                 $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' aria-hidden="true">';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
}
```

EDIT: Chittaranjan asked me for some more info so here goes:

I'm calling this new extension (`data_type_walker`) on the class `Walker_Nav_Menu` in my header.php file where my nav menu is located. Calling it as follows:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class'=> 'nav-menu', 'walker' => new data_type_walker() ) ); ?>
```

The output should be something like this:

```
<li class="all the various wordpress menu classes"><a href="url" data-icon="whatever input I choose in the Custom Menu Admin section" aria-hidden="true">navigation text link</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you add some more code like how you are calling this custom menu and how the output will be as per your expectation?

Comment: @Chittaranjan sure, added some more info :)

Comment: I added the above class to my functions.php file but do not see any effect/extra field on the admin menu screen. Am I missing anything?

Comment: yeah so you need to add this: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/3802459 to your functions.php as well, sorry I didn't make that very clear in my post. I then edited this code so it shows data-icon instead of color, but I can't link it up so that the value of data-icon input is displayed in the HTML :/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to toggle the CSS Classes checkbox under screen option, WP Admin > Appearance > Menus, and attach the icon to a CSS class.

And add your icons using psuedo selectors to the CSS class.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes a simpler solution is a better one, I genuinely think, from what was explained in the question, that @Lawless answer here is probably the sensible route.  You just add classes in here and in your style.css you add in the individual icons with pseudo-selectors as stated in the question.  Considering that you're essentially just trying to be able to target specific menu items, adding a class more efficient than writing a full function to add a data-icon attribute.